# jQuery .html(), .append() doesn't work on multiline markup

Tags: jquery, html

I have be trying to get the .html() or .append() function to render the markup returned from a third party plugin via an ajax call.

The ajax response (Which is coming back fine) looks something like:

```
<div>
        <!-- Start Third Party Markup -->       
            <div>
                <img id="Img1" usemap="#dnc_map_43" src="charts/solution_id_6/dnc-vvvgdwwl.png?634336319915542170" style="height:294px;width:628px;border-width:0px;" />
                        <map name="dnc_map_43" id="Map1"> 
                        <area shape="poly" coords="0,274,628,274,628,294,0,294" href="http://www.dotnetcharting.com" alt="Visit .netCHARTING for licensing options and more information." title="Visit .netCHARTING for licensing options and more information." />
                        <area shape="poly" coords="381,26,616,26,616,56,381,56" href="http://www.dotnetcharting.com" alt="Visit .netCHARTING for licensing options and more information." title="Visit .netCHARTING for licensing options and more information." />
                    </map>
            </div>
        <!-- End Third Party Markup -->  
</div>
```

However we have no control over the way the markup from the third party is formatted and I have discovered (After tearing my hair out all morning) that the .html() or .append() jQuery functions require the markup to be in either one line or escaped using "\" after each new line character.

Does anyone know a way around this?

Comment: if you include the jQuery code you are trying to use it would make it easier to answer your question

Comment: Actually, I was trying to parse the wrong part of the ajax response. Hence the problem. The .html() functions work fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If that is indeed true (although I can hardly imagine it is), you can use the `replace` method to replace `\n` and `\r` with <strike>an empty string</strike> a space.

Comment: +1 Though I'd replace with a space since `foo\nbar` as the linebreak would naturally display as a space anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Dose [this](http://jsfiddle.net/saranghdave/AgeXW/) solve your problem ? If not, please correct me.

Comment: Please add your code to your answer; you shouldn't oblige us to wander to a different site to see your actual solution. BTW, your string there doesn't contain any newlines...

Comment: What you're showing is concatenation of strings across several lines.  There's no newline in the final string. OP is asking how to append html to the DOM when the string contains newline characters. OP also mentioned he is not in control of the HTML, hence assignment is also not an issue.

Comment: +1 JSFiddle.net is a great tool to show prototype solution, I believe it is a widely used and accepted as answer, personally I rather see working prototype that is a click away than to have to build it myself by copying code

Answer (score 0):

I've run the following test with jquery 1.5 and it works fine for me.

```
<div id="one">
    <P>foo</p>
    <p>bar</p>
</div>
<div id="two"></div>

$('#two').html( $('#one').html() );
```

The second div correctly gets populated with the multiline markup from the first one.